# Numpy array format for fit_transform(image) TSNE method

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using Scikit-learn for tSNE to interrogate around 1000 scatterplots, but I appear to require a 2D numpy array to access the fit_transform method. I'm new to Python.

My code,

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import numpy as np
import cv2
mypath='/Path/to/files/scatterplots/'
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
photos = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)
for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
  photos[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,10), subplot_kw={'xticks':(), 'yticks':()})
for ax, img in zip(axes.ravel(), photos):
   ax.imshow(img)
```

**output**
[image]

**Problem code**

```
tsne = TSNE(random_state=50)
digits_tsne = tsne.fit_transform (photos.data)
```

**Error**

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)

```
892             Embedding of the training data in low-dimensional space.
893         """
```

--> 894         embedding = self._fit(X)

- 3 further lines of error output within t_sne.py

I believe the fit_transform method requires a 2D numpy array, e.g.

```
'target': array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

where 0-3 refer to the different data (parasites) behind each of the scatterplots 1-4.

**Request**
*How do I combine the target array into image numpy array so fit_transform can see it and process it?*

Comment: What's the shape of `photos.data`?

Comment: Thanks, print (photos.shape) .... output (4,). Just to explain, this is just an example data set.

Comment: In order to fit the algorithm you will need to feed it with data. In your case, the pixel values of each image. Try to run `fit_transform()` with a single image. I'm guessing that that image should have a 2D shape.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried and get the same error .. yes the image has a 2D shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check documentation for [t-SNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html):

> X : array, shape (n_samples, n_features)

For your case to work, you need to cast images to 1d array and assemble a matrix out of them.

Codewise, the following snippet should do the job of 2-dimensional t-SNE clustering:

```
arr = [cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n])).ravel() for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles))]
X = np.vstack[arr]
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty exciting ... I'll feed back here shortly.

Comment: Thank you again. The only difference is "X = np.vstack(arr)". The associated manuscript will take around 1 year for the paper to be published, but I will certainly acknowledge @SergeyBushmanov as an important source of help.